# JSTL c:set with HashMap

Tags: java, jboss, weblogic, jstl

We are in process of migrating a legacy application from one weblogic 12C (JDK 7) to JBoss 7.2 (JDK 8). However, while running the application, we are getting an error

*Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Invalid property in <set>:  "articleId"
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.SetSupport.**exportToBeanProperty**(SetSupport.java:244)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.SetSupport.doEndTag(SetSupport.java:96)*

Not sure why its going to exportToBean instead of exporttoMap.

Here is the piece of code which is causing the problem. The same works perfectly with weblogic.

```
<jsp:useBean id="editParams" class="java.util.HashMap" />
<c:set target="${editParams}" property="articleId" value="${row.id}" /> 
<c:set target="${editParams}" property="editable" value="true" />
```

Not sure what is missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.